# Highest (short) roots and commutation relations in (twisted) DAHA

Tags: coxeter-groups, hecke-algebras, root-systems, weyl-group

I am trying to understand, explicitly, the commutation relation between $X_\vartheta$ and $Y_\vartheta = T_0T_{s_\vartheta}$ in the (twisted) DAHA for a root system $R$, where $\vartheta$ is the highest short root for $R$.  Moreover, I am trying to express this commutation relation uniformly for any $R$.

For those unfamiliar with DAHA:

Is there some canonical (reduced) expression (in terms of simple reflections) for the reflection associated to the highest (short) root?

For example, write the highest (short) root as:
$$\vartheta = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n m_i\alpha_i$$
for simple roots $\{\alpha_i\}$.  Then can one, generally, write a reduced expression for $s_{\vartheta}$ in terms of $s_i$ and $m_i$?  An algorithm for writing such an expression will also suffice.

Also useful: how many occurences of $s_i$ such that $(\vartheta,\alpha_i)\neq 0$ are in a reduced expression for $s_\vartheta$?

I am mostly interested in the case of simply-laced $R$, but a general answer is better.